# need to push an array to an object

Tags: javascript

I need to push array to an object inside an object not able to perform this task. I am working on angular 6

Here is an example.

```
 abc = { data: { name: '', version: '', type: '', ports: [], vm:[] } };

  let hostlist = ['1234.Vm', '5678.Vm', '6789.Vm'];
//Need to push hostlist data to adc.data.vm
this.adc.data.vm.push(hostlist);
//this output is array inside array
this.adc.data.vm.concat(hostlist);
// concat cont work gives empty array
```

I need the output in this format

```
{ name: '', version: '', type: '', ports: [], vm:['1234.Vm', '5678.Vm', '6789.Vm'] }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either `push` with the spread operator or reassign `adc.data.vm` to the *result* of [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) (since `concat` returns a new array without changing existing arrays):

**Method 1: push() using the spread operator**

```js
// method 1: push with spread operator
let adc = {
  data: {
    name: '',
    version: '',
    type: '',
    ports: [],
    vm: []
  }
};
let hostlist = ['1234.Vm', '5678.Vm', '6789.Vm'];

adc.data.vm.push(...hostlist);
console.log(adc);
```

**Method 2: Reassign to the result of concat**

```js
let adc = {
  data: {
    name: '',
    version: '',
    type: '',
    ports: [],
    vm: []
  }
};
let hostlist = ['1234.Vm', '5678.Vm', '6789.Vm'];

adc.data.vm = adc.data.vm.concat(hostlist);
console.log(adc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always assign the object to that property:

```
abc.data.vm = abc.data.vm.concat(['1234.Vm', '5678.Vm', '6789.Vm']);
```